# ReactJS - async function in useEffect doesn't wait under any condition

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks

I have searched through possible solutions quite a bit and can't find any mistake that applies in this case. The await used inside useEffect just doesn't wait.

App.js: the data state is set only through default value and nowhere else

```
  const [data, setData] = useState( new Data() );

  useEffect(()=>{
    async function loadData() {
      await data.load();
    }
    loadData().then(()=>{ console.log('Loaded!') });
  }, [data])
```

data.js is ES6 class that has async method load():

```
async load() {
        let test = await fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/json-iterator/test-data/master/large-file.json");
        let testJson = await test.json();
    }
```

Whatever I try, the .then() is triggered within a split second, while opening the same json file in browser takes a long time.

**Things I tried:**

- Using null as default state and instead initializing on mount
  `useEffect( ()=>{setData( new Data() )}, [] )` (while adding check at
  top of data's useEffect to return if data is null)
- IIFE function inside data's useEffect using just await instead of then
- There are no fetching related warnings or errors in console, still I tried with just setTimeout instead
- Few other probably pointless things.. I can't figure out what is wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your code is working properly, you're just being confused at the caching behavior and the browser display behavior.

Your `load` method fetches the data properly. It does not throw an error. Then the `loadData` function properly chains that Promise with the caller, and the caller's `.then` is chained properly too.

`Loaded` is logged near-immediately because the request doesn't take long to finish at all - and this occurs because, if you've fetched that particular endpoint before, it will return a *locally cached version*.

[image]

If you clear the cache, or press the "Disable cache" button in the developer tools, you should see the request take multiple seconds to resolve.

> while opening the same json file in browser takes a long time.

This is because *rendering* that much content is expensive. It isn't necessarily downloading the data over the network - if it's only rendering the data from the *disk cache*, which it should, the problem is that formatting, displaying, paginating, and painting so much text takes a while to finish.

If you change this:

```
async load() {
        let test = await fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/json-iterator/test-data/master/large-file.json");
        let testJson = await test.json();
    }
```

to do something else once the request finishes - such as trigger a state change and do more stuff with the data - you should see things working properly.

Answer (score 1):

I have check async behaviour of your code ...

```
useEffect(()=>(async () => {
    console.warn("1:- ", new Date());
    const resp = await fetch(
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/json-iterator/test-data/master/large-file.json"
    );
    const json = await resp.json();
    console.log(json);
    console.warn("3:- ", new Date());
  })(), []);
```

1. Disable the catching from network tab
2. simulate network type as a slow 3G o see the result

[image: img]